# how to apply enum for the following code. rule is enum values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, rest, api

```
try (Statement statementGroup2 = connection.createStatement()) {
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery3)) {
        try (ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            while (result.next()) {
                adminmain2.setRule(result.getString("rule"));
                adminmain2.setDescription(result.getString("description"));
                adminmain.add(adminmain2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the unused `Statement` there?

Comment: what would you like to transform into an enum?

Comment: rule is having 4 enum values

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's being asked here. It is ambiguous, vague, overly broad, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current state.